# Google Analytics event tracking not reported

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

Quite a ways back we switched from ga() to gtag() and the Global Site Tag. Ever since, we have not been able to get event tracking to report. I added an alert to the Global Site Tag and it shows that the gtag() function is being called. That alert is not shown in the code below, having been removed.

The following code is from the top of the web page I am testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    
    gtag('config', '***********');
    gtag('config', '*************');
</script>
<script>
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','***********');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

The account numbers are obfuscated. However, normal Google Analytics reporting is occurring. So the account is set up properly for that.

As a test I have added the following code to a link on the page:

```
<a onclick="gtag('event', 'screen_view', {'app_name': 'myAppName', 'screen_name': 'Home'});" href="https://www.rephunter.net/blog">The RepHunter Blog - Discussion and Tips For Independent Sales Reps or Those Looking For Them</a>
```

According to the Google documentation, the above should be all that is needed, yet there is no reporting in either the Behavior section or the realtime section.

Originally I had my own names for the parameters in the gtag(), but when they did not work, I fell back to an example taken directly from https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/api.

What else is needed to perform event tracking?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation in [here](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/api#event) it has advised placing the global snippet above the `gtag` event commands, otherwise, it will be not sent to analytics.

[image]
So you might need to add the Google Analytics specific snippet in the beginning of the `<head>` tag on the same page.

From [gtag doc](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/snippet)

> The global snippet must appear at the top of every page on your site. gtag() commands cannot send data unless a global snippet appears on the page, and that snippet appears above where any gtag() commands are called.

Other Google Analytics related reportings might be working assuming that you have configured Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager through a tag with the type of Universal Analytics  (or your approach might be different)

Comment: In my original attempt to create this code, the Google Analytics snippet is the first line after the <head> as shown in the original question. I am not sure how it would be possible to "move it above" that. What am I missing?

Comment: @JeffreySimon - What are the Google products you configured with `gtag('config', '***********');` in the global snippet? You should correctly add the ID of the Google Analytics property in there.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, the account numbers are deliberated obfuscated here. The normal GA functions work, so the accounts are set up properly.

Comment: The codes start with UA, which is the GA property id, and AW, which I think is Adwords Conversion tracking. Does that answer the question? Event tracking used to work for us.

Comment: @JeffreySimon Yes, seems those configurations are correct.